# Invision 3.4 sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to remove certain images from one forum of my site. For example if I use the following

UPDATE forums_posts SET post = REPLACE(post, 'hep', 'help')

That will remove hep and replace it with the word help, across the entire board.

What I would like is that to only apply to one forum, forum id 3. But looking in the post table there is nothing that assigns each topic to a forum, that is in the topics table - forum_id.

So, I need that query to work where topic_id (posts table) = tid (topics table) and forum_id = 3 (topics table)

Anyone? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `join` in your SQL statement:

```
UPDATE forums_posts p JOIN
       Topics t
       on p.topic_id = t.tid
    SET p.post = REPLACE(p.post, 'hep', 'help')
    WHERE t.forum_id = 3;
```

If of interest, this is MySQL-specific syntax.  The ANSI SQL equivalent would be:

```
UPDATE forums_posts p
    SET post = REPLACE(post, 'hep', 'help')
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Topics t
                  WHERE p.topic_id = t.tid AND t.forum_id = 3
                 );
```

Comment: ibf_posts and ibf_topics are my tables, does the above still apply if i change forums_posts to ibf_posts, or does topics need changing to ibf_topics as well?

Comment: @MarkS . . . The SQL code needs to have your actual table names in order to work.